# control seaborn regplot confidence intervals translucency

Tags: python, seaborn, transparency, regplot

Anyone has a way to control the degree of translucency of the confidence intervals in seaborn regplot?
It's been bugging me (especially for black background plots) for a while and I still could not find anything on that topic.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,2)), columns=["x","y"])
sns.regplot('x', 'y', data=data)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `alpha` for the confidence interval band using `matplotlib.pyplot.setp` like:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,2)), columns=["x","y"])
ax = sns.regplot('x', 'y', data=data)
plt.setp(ax.collections[1], alpha=0.2)
```

Just for reference, If you want to look at elements of a seaborn plot you can use ax.get_children().

Comment: the line `plt.setp(ax.collections[1], alpha=0)` is pure magic. I wanted to get rid of the confidence interval fill color.